# how to keep user login session without autologout in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I want to keep user login,not allow to autologout

this is config file code :

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 720000;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ospos_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

how to change this config file ,for keep user login without autologout

Comment: If you would like a non-expiring session set the value of $config['sess_expiration'] to zero: 0 http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to `$config['sess_expiration']=0;`

New Code :

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 0;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = PHP_INT_MAX;
```